# c++: Is virtuality skipping generations?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I was expecting to find easily the answer for that one, but searching around yielded nothing.

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void whoAmI()
    {
        std::cout << "\nI'm base\n" ;     
    }       
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};


class SecondDerivative : public Derived
{
public:
    virtual void whoAmI()
    {
        std::cout << "\nI'm Second derivative\n" ;     
    }       
};

int main()
{
    SecondDerivative SD;
    Base* b = &SD;
    b->whoAmI();
    return 0;     
}
```

I know that the virtual function of the run time type should be called when using a pointer. But In this example, the direct derived class doesn't implement the virtual function, and yet its derived class's function is called when using the original base class pointer.

Building with g++ and running shows:

`I'm Second derivative`

I want to know if there is a compelling rule regarding such a case in the standard or is it platform dependent?

Comment: No, polymorphism isn't platform dependent.

Comment: Isn't there any explicit reference to this in the standard? I couldn't find one.

Comment: You won't find any explicit statements that say "this isn't platform dependent".

Comment: Your program is behaving 100% as expected. This is the entire point of virtual functions. If you override it, your override is called, even if calling it from a pointer to the base class. It does not matter if every class along the way overrides the function or not.

Comment: @Lunchian, I'm seeking for a statement like: "Even if the direct derived did't implement the virtual function, the rules go on to its derived classes".

Comment: @Subway, N3485 § 10.3/3 has an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a compelling rule regarding such a case in the standard or is it platform dependent?

Your code example shows standard polymorphism in C++, it is **not** platform dependent.

```
  Base* b = &SD;
  b->whoAmI();
```

You used base class pointer to point to derived class (SecondDerivative in this case) objects, when you call the virtual function, which function to call is decided at run-time, in this case, `whoAmI` of `SecondDerivative` is called. You may want to also look at `virtual function` and `vtable` about how polymorphism in C++ is implemented. *When your derived class does not override the base class version of the virtual function, base class version is used*. See a live demo here: [Virtual function Demo](http://ideone.com/CwjU70)

Answer (score 1):

It would work like this:

- Base::whoAmI() -> I'm base
- Derived::whoAmI() -> I'm base
- SecondDerivative::whoAmI() -> I'm Second derivative

b->whoAmI() would call SecondDerivative::whoAmI(), unless there are special circumstances. For example if you are calling whoAmI() from the Base::Base() it would call Base::whoAmI(), not SecondDerivative::whoAmI() even if the object is SecondDerivative.

This is standard C++ behavior, not platform dependent.